# Unable to receive onSensorChanged evens inside Work Manager when the app is in Background

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager, android-12, proximitysensor

I have an app which listens to a broadcast and on receiving the broadcast it starts a **work manager** immediately. the workManager keeps listening to sensor data's like **Proximity, Accelerometer and Magnetometer**. I'm using a timer to keep the workManager running until certain conditions are satisfied. below is my workManager implementation which implements **SensorEventListener**

```
class CustomWorkManager(appContext: Context, private val parameters: WorkerParameters) :
CoroutineWorker(appContext, parameters), SensorEventListener
```

I'm getting the sensor data by overriding the **onSensorChanged** method while the app is in the foreground. the problem is when the app goes into the background (ie. app is closed) and we receive a broadcast the **work manager is initiated but i'm not getting events on onSensorChanged method**. Now according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#only-gather-sensor-data-in-the-foreground) its said that for (**API level 28) or higher** we will have to listen to sensor data when your app is in the **foreground or as part of a foreground service**.

So I tried running a workManager with **setForeground** method, but still i'm unable to get any events for onSensorChanged method if the app is in the **background**. So is it not possible to get sensor data for API > 28 inside a workManager even if we set setForeground? since its mentioned in the documentation that it's suggested to use foreground service and for  **Apps that target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher can't start foreground services while running in the background due to the [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions) , except for a few special cases**. so we have no other option than to run a work manager and try to listen to sensor data.

*So does this mean we won't be able to listen to sensor data (Proximity, Accelerometer, Magnetometer) inside a workManager when the app is in the background ?*

*If anybody has any insights reg this please help.*

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @ShashankPednekar No haven't gotten any solution as of yet :(